# Getting min and max dates formatted using zoo package on r

Tags: r, date, max, min

I have a data frame which has a variable where month and year combined.  A small reproducible example:

```
c("MARCH-2016", "FEBRUARY-2016", "NOVEMBER-2016", "OCTOBER-2016", 
"OCTOBER-2016", "OCTOBER-2016")
```

I have converted this to `yearmon` class using the following code from the zoo package.

```
yearmn <- zoo::as.yearmon(yearmn, format = "%B-%Y")
```

I received the following output:

```
[1] "Mar 2016" "Feb 2016" "Nov 2016" "Oct 2016" "Oct 2016" "Oct 2016"
```

I have converted this to a date format without any trouble:

```
yearmn <- as.Date(yearmn, frac = 0.01)
```

Output:

[1] "2016-03-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-11-01" "2016-10-01" "2016-10-01" "2016-10-01"

When I run the str(yearmn) I get the following output:

```
Date[1:65535], format: "2016-03-01" "2016-02-01"
```

I want to use min and max functions on this "yearmn" field - but the following code returns NA

```
min(yearmn)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I get `min(yearmn)#[1] "2016-02-01"`

Comment: @akrun not sure where I am going wrong? but getting NA's for both min and max functions.

Comment: Try `min(yearmn, na.rm = T)`

Comment: The `frac = 0.01` argument could be omitted as the default is the start of the period.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions...apparently I had some junk characters in some cells.....the same codes worked perfectly when I removed them....thank you